# Excel dates in sequential orders

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I want to know how I can have sequential dates in a row
Example I need the dates to show in this format 
Cell m1 Monday, June 3, 2017
Cell 2 Tuesday, June 4, 2017
Cell 3 Wednesday, June 5, 2017

And continuing to end of year

Comment: Do two things: type `6/3/2017` until `6/5/2017`, and drag it down until `12/31/2017`, then format the ranges as `Date` with the required format (it's Excel built-in format)

Answer (score 1):

Just write your first Date 06/03/2017 and use Custom Format:
`dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy`

and drag the date in the Row if it doesn't increment click on the paste options and choose Fill series

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Vylix's comment, I start with a couple of assumptions. If these are not valid, then adjust the instructions as appropriate:

1. You actually meant "in a column" instead of "in a row". Columns go down, rows go across. No big deal either way.
2. Your localisation settings are set to expect dates in mon/day/year instead of day/mon/year. Again, just swap the details to suit.

Then just follow these steps:

1. Enter 6/3/2017 in cell 1. Enter 6/4/2017 in cell 2.
2. Select both cells and then drag the drag handle (the small black box at the bottom right of the selected cells) down until you've reached enough cells to get to the end of the year.
3. Right click the selected cells and click "Format Cells...".
4. Select Date and configure as you wish.